# Python Pandas: How to add rows between two datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Pandas DataFrame and I'm trying to figure out how to insert values between the datetime values in my DF. Ideally I'd have a row for each hour, with the 'price' just being filled in by the previous price.

If I have a table like this:

```
day_hour                price
---------------------------------
2020-01-01 05:00:00     12.083333
2020-01-01 09:00:00     11.047170
2020-01-01 10:00:00     11.678125
2020-01-01 11:00:00     11.920000
2020-01-01 12:00:00     12.012500
```

How would I turn it into this?:

```
day_hour                price
---------------------------------
2020-01-01 05:00:00     12.083333
2020-01-01 06:00:00     12.083333
2020-01-01 07:00:00     12.083333
2020-01-01 08:00:00     12.083333
2020-01-01 09:00:00     11.047170
2020-01-01 10:00:00     11.678125
2020-01-01 11:00:00     11.920000
2020-01-01 12:00:00     12.012500
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) then [`resample.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html) to hourly (`1H`) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to restore the column:

```
df = df.set_index('day_hour').resample('1H').ffill().reset_index()
```

`df`:

```
             day_hour      price
0 2020-01-01 05:00:00  12.083333
1 2020-01-01 06:00:00  12.083333
2 2020-01-01 07:00:00  12.083333
3 2020-01-01 08:00:00  12.083333
4 2020-01-01 09:00:00  11.047170
5 2020-01-01 10:00:00  11.678125
6 2020-01-01 11:00:00  11.920000
7 2020-01-01 12:00:00  12.012500
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day_hour': pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01 05:00:00', '2020-01-01 09:00:00',
                                '2020-01-01 10:00:00', '2020-01-01 11:00:00',
                                '2020-01-01 12:00:00']),
    'price': [12.083333, 11.04717, 11.678125, 11.92, 12.0125]
})
```